# FCM Swift - Send Individual Notification doesn't work in Console

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I get token on the console with this method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
        let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(deviceToken.bytes)
        var tokenString = ""

        for i in 0..<deviceToken.length {
            tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
        }

        //Tricky line
        FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Unknown)
        print("Device Token:", tokenString)
}
```

When I go send an individual notification on [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com), I get status `failed`, but when I  send group notifications, it works. Any help?

Comment: try retrieving the token string from the InstanceID object.
FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()

Comment: Yes, its worked. Thanks